# From where to load application content

Tags: java, android, store

I am bulding an app that needs to load multiple long texts into multiple Textviews. The data will never change. Is it better to store the data in Strings or in one Textfile and load it every time the app starts?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check my answer.

Comment: If I have answered your question then please mark my answer as "solution".

Answer (score 2):

Store them in Strings resources (strings.xml) and then refer them to your `TextView` in layout. Like this:

XML file saved at res/values/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello!</string>
</resources>
```

This layout XML applies a string to a View:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

You can learn more about them [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#String).